# Save numpy arrray to file with variable name as file name: Python

Tags: python, arrays, filenames

I have a large number of masked np arrays which I would like to save to .nc files. I would like the files to have the same names as the current variable names for the np arrays.

```
import numpy.ma as ma
arr = np.array([[5,9,2],[4,3,9],[6,3,1]])
var = ma.masked_array(arr, mask=False)
```

I would like to save this array to the folder 'Saved_files', ending up with 'Saved_files/var.nc' as the filename, such that

```
filename = 'Saved_files/' + ?? + '.nc'
print(filename)
```

Produces 'Saved_files/var.nc'

and then this can be saved to file

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
ncfile = Dataset(filename, mode = 'w', format = 'NETCDF4')
ncfile.createDimension('x', var.shape[1])
ncfile.createDimension('y', var.shape[0])
data = ncfile.createVariable('data', np.float64, ('y','x'))
data[:,:] = var[:,:]
ncfile.close()
```

Is it possible to create a string (??) with the name of the variable to automate this process?

I have not managed to find any ways to do this so far.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function that looks for the variable in global namespaces and use that to make your file name and save in it.

here is an example

```
def varName(x,namespace):
    return [i for i in namespace if namespace[i] is x]
a=np.zeros((2,2))
print(varName(a,globals()))
```